# MVC3 app redirects to ReturnUrl=%2f

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I am using Form Authentication in my MVC3 web app. I have added following in root web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".FormsAuth" loginUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="2880" />            
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

When I launch my app, it redirects to `http://localhost:22888/Home/Index?ReturnUrl=%2f` instead `http://localhost:22888`. If I remove line `<deny users="?">` then it redirects correctly but then `Context.User.Identity.Name` gives no value after login.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by performing two modifications:

1. I removed deny users='?' line from web.config file. But then I was getting null in `Context.User.Identity.Name`
2. In HttpPost Login method, I was redirecting user after successful authentication using `return View("Home")`. When I changed it to `return RedirectToAction("Home")` I got value in `Context.User.Identity.Name`

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Securing your ASP.NET MVC 4 App and the new AllowAnonymous Attribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx).

> You cannot use routing or web.config files to secure your MVC application (Any Version). **The only supported way to secure your MVC application is to apply the Authorize attribute** ...

[Quote](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2010/08/24/securing-your-mvc-application.aspx)

> MVC uses routes and does not map URLs to physical file locations like WebForms, PHP and traditional web servers. **Therefore using web.config will definitely open a security hole in your site.**

[The product team will have a communication if this changes in the future, but for now it is  without exception the rule.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1583850.aspx/1/10)

Examples:

Start with the default ASP.Net MVC project (internet/intranet).

Edit the web.config adding:

```
<location path="Home">
  <system.web>
    <authoirzation>
      <deny users="*">
    </authoirzation>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Run the project, by default you will use the *Default* route `/Home/Index` and you see content, simply bypassing the web.config with no changes to the default template.  Why?  Because the ASP.Net pipeline is comparing the URL requested to the location specified in the web.config.  However, **after** the Authorization Event has been executed in the pipeline the routing taking place (Default routing or custom routing) and allows access to the supposedly restricted area.

Additionally, any MVC `Redirect()` will also by-pass the same security measures as again the routing takes place after the Authorization Pipeline Event.

> When I launch my app, it redirects to http://:22888/Home/Index?ReturnUrl=%2f instead http://:22888.

If you are using the default template, authorization stores the `returnUrl` and redirects back to `/Home/Index` with the value `%2f` which is `/`.  You can update the `RedirectToAction` code in the `AccountsController` to not append the `returnUrl` if it is `/`.

Comment: I disagree strongly with the tact Microsoft is taking on this.  I get they're trying to impress on people that it requires careful attention to make your app secure by using the web.config, but it does "definitely" open a security hole, and the only examples they can give are pretty lame.  Yeah, you can reach an action by a default route or a specific route.  You can map that in web.config just as easily.  More importantly, a simple web.config authorization that denies access to everything except specific url's is perfect secure.  I think MS is doing a huge disservice by lying to people.

Comment: Even if we say what should be said, that using web.config requires careful attention, I also strongly disagree with their claim that you must use the Authorize attribute, and nothing else.  Authorize is just an AuthorizationFilter implementation, of which you can achieve the same thing through several different ways.. either writing your own filter (not even derived from AuthorizeAttribute), or using a base class that overrides OnAuthorization (which is executed at the same point in the pipeline).  These absolute statements are wrong and outright dishonest.

Comment: So rewriting what they wrote, yes that will work, but it doesn't change that web.config is will absolutely always open a security flaw in a MVC website.  You've again countered what I've said with no proof.

Comment: No, it won't absolutely always open a security flaw.  It *MIGHT* open a security flaw, if you are not careful or don't know what you're doing.. but it doesn't absolutely do so.  Unless you can show how using Windows Authentication and denying access to everything at the root of the site by non-authenticated users in web.config creates a security flaw, i'd like to know how.

Comment: How can I prove something doesn't exist?  It's impossible.  You are asserting it does exist.  It should be easy to prove then.

Comment: Additionally, it's extremely dishonest and very bad practice to tell people they can use the web.config out of the box.  This is, as my code has demonstrated not to be the case, if you'd like to make a point of re-create an authorization system, then it will work but as my links point, it's not the *supported* way to security an MVC website.

Comment: Yes, your example would have a security hole, because the author did not consider how default routes work.  But, as I said, using Windows Authentication, at the root of the web site, deny all unauthenticated users in the web.config.  There is no security hole.  It's just not there.  So saying that using web.config absolutely always creates a hole is simply not true.  It's also not true if the author HAS in fact considered all the route possibilities.

Comment: There is also a difference between saying "using the web.config may work, but it is likely to introduce a security vulnerability if you are not careful and we do not support it" and "It's impossible to use the web.config and using anything other than the authorize attribute will absolutely always cause the universe to explode violently".  Ok, so I exaggerated a bit there at the end, but that's the way it comes off.  You and others from MS are making absolute statements that it's impossible to do things, and that things will always happen when that is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct behavior of the runtime.

You told the engine to deny the access to unauthenticated users and also that the login url is located at `~/Home/Index`.

This is why when you navigate to the default url `/` the engine makes the browser go to the login page and passes the return url, encoded `/` in this case.

The question is then: what you want to do if the correct behavior bothers you.

Comment: okay, i removed deny user line and now it redirected correctly. But I am getting null value for `Context.User.Identity.Name` even though I have set `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(adminData.Username, false);`

Comment: If you remove the denial, you probably won't hit the login page. Also, if you set the forms cookie, the `Context.User.Identity.Name` is not available instantly, only upon next request.

Comment: You have to make another Request before `Context.User.Identity` is available, this is standard in all ASP.Net applications.  Typically after setting the cookie, do a Redirect then it will be available.

Answer (score 0):

Although a little late to the show, if you're still having issues, remember to look down at the  sections in your web.config for other authorization rules (correctly or incorrectly set).  There are some situations where mis-configurations to a resource at the root or subdirectory could cause endless redirects.